# Objective-C Realm Migration : new table migration

Tags: objective-c, migration, realm

I downloaded realm migration example for objective-C. I cannot find any script that write for adding new table while doing migration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No migration is needed to add a new object type. The table is automatically created when the existing Realm file is opened.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change schema version and Realm will automatically perform the migration for adding new tables.

Comment: I add new Realm classes all the time without needing to change the schema version.  I only change the schema version if a Realm class has changed its schema, necessitating a migration.